# I/flutter ( 9532): Binding has not yet been initialized, when create database

Tags: flutter, async-await, sqflite

I'm building an app with `sqflite` database, when I run my app i got this error:

> I/flutter ( 9532): eeeeeeeee Binding has not yet been initialized.
> I/flutter ( 9532): The "instance" getter on the ServicesBinding binding mixin is only available once that binding has been initialized.
> I/flutter ( 9532): Typically, this is done by calling "WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()" or "runApp()" (the latter calls the former). Typically this call is done in the "void main()" method. The "ensureInitialized" method is idempotent; calling it multiple times is not harmful. After calling that method, the "instance" getter will return the binding.
> I/flutter ( 9532): In a test, one can call "TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()" as the first line in the test's "main()" method to initialize the binding.
> I/flutter ( 9532): If ServicesBinding is a custom binding mixin, there must also be a custom binding class, like WidgetsFlutterBinding, but that mixes in the selected binding, and that is the class that must be constructed before using the "instance" getter. nnnnnnnnnnnn

here is my `main()`

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized;
  await DBHelper().initDb();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

and here is the `initDB()`

```
  initDb() async {
    try {
      String databasePath = await getDatabasesPath(); //The break point stops here and show me the error above.

      String path = join(databasePath, 'task.db');

      Database ourdb = await openDatabase(path,
          onCreate: _onCreate, version: _version, onUpgrade: _onUpgrade);

      return ourdb;
    } catch (e) {
      print('eeeeeeeee $e nnnnnnnnnnnn');
    }
  }
```

So what is goes wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized` is just a statement - you should execute the function.

Replace `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized` with `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()`.